# Desactivating touchpad with one keystroke

Tags: debian, touchpad, synaptic

I would like to desactivate/activate the touchpad of my Dell Lattitue 6430u with Fn+F5. This keystroke doesn't work by default on debian unstable.

I know how to do this but it requires two different keystrokes.

```
$ synclient TouchpadOff=1 
$ synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

Do you know a "toggle" command ?

Comment: Does anything appear in the system logs when you press the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you should do:

```
#!/bin/bash
synclient TouchpadOff=$(synclient -l | grep -c 'TouchpadOff.*=.*0')
```

Save that as `/usr/local/bin/touchpad.sh`, chmod it to be executable (`chmod 770 /usr/local/bin/touchpad.sh` should be enough? too much?). Since we placed it in a bin it *should* be part of your PATH, if it isn't you need to add it. Then we just make a keyboard-shortcut as Fn+F5 and make it call that script.